# slfj4 logging - MDC.put function not printing anything

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, mdc

I am trying to print the username who has logged in along with their id in the logs using slfj4 MDC class. Here is my code, please tell me where i am wrong.

**JAVA FILE -**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public classResponse getuser(@PathVariable("user_id") Integer user_id, @RequestParam(value = "department_id", required = false) Integer department_id) {
    JSONObject response = null;
    String username = getUserName();
    logger.debug("Testing MDC.");
    MDC.put("FirstName", "First");
    MDC.put("LastName", "Last");
    logger.info(":::ServiceContoller.getuser starts for userid" + user_id);
    logger.info(":::ServiceContoller.getCreateEnvironment:Ends for username" + username);
    try {
        response = classServiceImpl.getUser1(username, user_id, department_id);
        logger.info("Sending Environment details - {}", response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return new ClassResponse(Constants.STR_ERROR, "Error getting USERDetails");
    }
    return new ClassResponse(Constants.STR_SUCCESS, response);
}
```

**XML PROPERTIES FILE - logback.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout>
      <Pattern>%-4r [%thread] %-5level C:%X{FirstName} N:%X{LastName} - %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>       
  </appender>

  <root> 
  <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

Please tell me what more I need to have or where I am wrong. Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this.. https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this also. But didn't worked. Found one very good project : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-mapped-diagnostic-contexts-mdc-example/
It solved my problem.

Comment: can you able to find out what is the issue ?